# discord.js v13 making a reaction collector

Tags: node.js, collections, discord, discord.js, bots

I am trying to make a reaction collector in discord.js v13 here is my code :

```
   message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]}).then(function (message) {
message.react("✅")

 const filter = (reaction, user) => {
                   return reaction.emoji.name === '✅' && user.id === message.author.id;
                };
                
                const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, {
max: 1,
time: 60000,
                   })
                   collector.on('collect', (collected) => {
const reaction = collected.first();

                     message.delete();
                     message.channel.send("test")

})
})
```

Comment: You've been a member of Stack Overflow for quite some time now and you should know that with a description like _"but it wont work"_ we can't do much. You should probably read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask first

Comment: sorry for that sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

`client` was missing the `DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS` intent.

**Original:**

You're creating your `collector` on the message that initiated the command, not on the message that your bot sends.

Do this instead:

```
const MSG = await message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]});
await MSG.react("✅");
```

Then, you need to create your collector on `MSG`, like this:

```
const collector = MSG.createReactionCollector({
  filter, 
  max: 1,
  time: 60000,
})
```

You also do not need `const reaction = collected.first();`, since your filter only allows "✅" reactions and a `max` of 1.

```
collector.on('collect', (collected) => {
  message.delete();
  message.channel.send("text");
})
```

Comment: still not working

Comment: see edited message

Comment: still same no response after clicking the emoji.

Comment: look at the last part of the again edited message

Comment: Still not working 

Comment: Check the top of the once-again-again edited message. If this doesn't work, well damn.

Comment: i added the "DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS" cuz my application is on dm and it worked tysm